# SQL Query Optimisation: Comparing Adjacent Rows

Tags: sql, query-optimization

I currently have the following query that takes a LONG time to execute

```
SELECT * FROM Table t1
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT * FROM Table t2
    WHERE
    (
        t1.Key = t2.Key - 1
        AND t1.Foo = 1
        AND t2.Bar = 0
    )
)
```

The `Key` is the primary key field. I am only comparing adjacent rows, so intuitively it seems the quickest implementation would be to compare all pairs of adjacent rows, N-1 say. The way my query works, I think it may be comparing each row with every other row in `Table`, i.e. taking N*N comparisons.

Is there a better way to write the query?

Comment: `Is there a better way to write the query?`. No. it is perfect, and a typical DBMS would not perform N*N row-comparisons, but instead use some kind of mergejoin. In this case the question is better than solution in the selected answer, IMO.

Comment: BTW: please use sane _metasyntactic_ names; either foo/bar or apple/orange or `my_table` or whatever. But **don't** name your table `table` and your key `key`. You would not name your child `child`, would you?

Comment: My DBMS didn't seem to do a mergejoin. Brad's answer ran 4 times faster than this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like:

```
Select t1.*
From table t1
inner join table t2
on t1.key = t2.key - 1
where t1.Foo = 1
and t2.Bar = 0
```

I tested this on a table that has a couple million rows and it ran in ~10 seconds.

Comment: This is wrong, since this will select the columns from the t2 alias as well. (or is it a table?). (also: the `from table t1` syntax is wrong)

Comment: I fixed issue 1, I don't understand issue 2.  Of course in certain DBs `table` is a keyword but it seems that this doesn't bother the questioner.

Comment: Well, it appears the OP named his table `table`, which is rather silly IMHO. You would not name your child `child` would you? BTW: I don't think that the `t1.*` syntax is standard ANSI-SQL but an extension used by a few implementations. (I still think the `EXISTS (..)` version is cleaner, because it avoids the _leaking_ of the t2 alias into the outer query)

Comment: I just assumed the OP just posted a toy problem.  I completely agree naming something table (or key!) is silly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM Table t1 
LEFT JOIN Table t2 ON (t1.Key = t2.Key-1) 
WHERE t1.Foo=1 AND t2.Bar = 0
```

Left join basically filters out non-existent rows FROM table B (in this case - t2). A rule of thumb is to avoid subqueries if they are not necessary, or if you are not sure they will perform well (fast).

Also make sure you use proper indexation (besides Key, I would make an index on pair of fields: (Foo, Bar)